# Does Ubuntu LiveCD automatically create a SWAP partition?

Tags: hard-drive, live-usb, live-environment

Forgive my noob-tastic question, but I'm very confused by what I'm seeing. I was trying to recover a drive, and was always told to make a LiveCD and run that. When I ran the LiveCD from boot, I started by running `lsblk`. Here is the result.

[image]

I could be mistaken, but I think that the Ubuntu LiveCD has gone and created a SWAP partition right at the head of the disk I was trying to recover.

`sdb` is the flash drive that I was using, as far as I can tell. It has the right size, approximately 32ish GB, and the drive i was trying to recover from was a 1TB drive, which is `sda`. `lsblk` was the first command I ran when I started the Live Environment. Any thoughts? Should I write this drive off as unrecoverable? Or am I misunderstanding what I'm reading?

Comment: Is it at all possible the drive *had* swap space at the beginning of the disk?  The Live images do not create any partitions or modify any partitions unless you do it manually or run an install command.

Comment: @thomasw it's possible, does Windows usually put a swap partition there?

Comment: Why don't you try mounting partitions 2 and 3 before assuming anything is wrong with the drive?  Mounting the disk is almost never correct  because the mountable filesystems are (usually) put into partitions. You'll need to guess the type of filesystem for the mount's -t switch -- e.g. -t ext4

Comment: LiveCD wont create partition unless you tell it to. If there is a swap partition though, it will use it.

Comment: @ubfan1 I can't mount partitions 2 and 3, it says that the drive is busy, and when I unmount swap, it says those are not ntfs partitions.

Comment: Make directories /mnt/tmp2 and /mnt/tmp3 and use those as mount points.  Use df to see if the sda2 and sda3 are really already mounted somewhere.

Comment: @ubfan1 I checked `mount` and `mount | grep "sda"` and neither of those showed sda2 and sda3 as mounted anywhere. I also created a `/mnt2' and a `/mnttemp` folder. Both of these returned the same message. I looked at `fdisk -l`, and it looks like it thinks the NTFS partition is a Linux/Solaris partition. I think that I need to install something for the LiveCD to read NTFS, because it keeps returning the message "NTFS signature missing."

Answer (score 0):

The Live images do not alter the partition tables of disks unless you are manually editing them (via command line or `gparted`), or are installing Ubuntu to the disk.

You assume that the Live images made alterations and that there's no partitions on the disk that are readable based on `lsblk`.  You need to try running `sudo fdisk -l` to list the actual data about partitions and their file types (unless it's a GPT partition table but it probably isn't).  More than likely, the disk you are working with *has* a swap partition already in place on the disk.  The Live images *do* auto mount swap partitions in an attempt to get swap, when a swap partition already exists.

Don't forget to try and mount `sda2` and `sda3` before assuming the drive is damaged and irrecoverable.  It's very unlikely that a swap partition at the beginning of the disk would indicate drive death, especially if the other two partitions mount fine and the data there is accessible.

<sub>And in follow up to your comment on whether Windows does this, Windows doesn't use swap partitions.</sub>

Comment: "And in follow up to your comment on whether Windows does this, Windows doesn't use swap partitions." Ok, that is a windows drive that I was trying to recover. I tried mounting sda2 and sda3, but was told the drive is busy. When I unmounted swap, it told me an ntfs partition could not be found.

Comment: @JFA and what's the output of `sudo fdisk -l`?  Add it as an edit to your original question.